# How to retrieve time of last edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have a Google Sheets that updates automatically throughout every day but sometimes gets stopped up. I want to store and update the time and date of the last time any cell in the first column is changed in a single cell.

For example: 
1. I open a sheet. 
2. The sheet automatically pulls and updates a .csv file from a server.
3. The cells are regenerated and updated. 
4. When any cell in the first column is changed
 
5. Update the time of the last edit in a cell of another sheet.

Comment: How does the second point works? Is it through scripting?

Comment: You must have an `onOpen()` function?  Is that what changes cells in the first column?  Or is it done manually?

Comment: I have built a script that does the second point with an onOpen( ) funtion

Answer (score 0):

I use this :

```
DocsList.getFileById("myID_Spreadsheet").getLastUpdated()
```

Comment: would I use an onOpen( ) funtcion and plave that inside? a variable has to go inside of .getLastUpdated(), correct? How do I post it to a specific cell in another spreadsheet?